# Ошибка при сохранении docx файла

Tags: c#

Здравия. Делаю простой редактор docx файлов (только текст). При попытке сохранить файл вылезает ошибка: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Приложению Word не удалось сохранить данный файл, так как он используется другим процессом.

Код функции сохранения:

```
    Word._Application app = new Word.Application();
    Word._Document word_doc = app.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
    Word.Paragraph para = word_doc.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
    para.Range.Text = text_editor.Text;
    para.Range.InsertParagraph();
    object filename = def_save_path;
    word_doc.SaveAs2(ref filename, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
        ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

    object save_changes = false;
    word_doc.Close(ref save_changes, oMissing, oMissing);
    app.Quit(ref save_changes, oMissing, oMissing);
    changed = false;
```

Comment: ну так вы закройте его сначала в том редакторе, котором открыли.

Comment: Дополнительно ничего не открыто. Там же новый файл создается.

Comment: я с Interop сто лет не работал, почему вы выбрали именно его? Делатете что то для старых версий ворда? Почему не что то, что работает с OpenXML?

Comment: Просто загуглил как через c# работать с ворд. Певрое то что вышло. Есть чтото поновее и лучше?

Comment: ну, например [вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-word-processing-document-by-providing-a-file-name), там даже целый готовый пример есть для создания документа

Comment: Мне кажется что вы когда загружаете документ в поток, не выгружаете его обратно и он не может после этого перезаписаться, так как открыт в вашем приложении. После того как загружаете текст в форму, закройте этот поток/метод.

Answer (score 1):

Пример для работы с OpenXML из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-word-processing-document-by-providing-a-file-name), для его работы необходимо установить nuget пакет [`DocumentFormat.OpenXml`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/)

```
public static void CreateWordprocessingDocument(string filepath)
{
    // Create a document by supplying the filepath. 
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
        WordprocessingDocument.Create(filepath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        // Add a main document part. 
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

        // Create the document structure and add some text.
        mainPart.Document = new Document();
        Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
        Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
        Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
        run.AppendChild(new Text("Create text in body - CreateWordprocessingDocument"));
    }
}
```

Результат

[image: ...]